# Ember: "import Route from '@ember/routing/route';" throws error in Console

Tags: javascript, ember.js, import, routes, importerror

I'm following the [Ember Quick Start guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/getting-started/quick-start/) (`ember-cli` v 2.11), and building the toy app along with the instructions.  In the "Define A Route" section, the instructions say to run the command `ember generate route scientists`, which adds the route to `router.js` and creates a new `scientists.js` file in the `routes` folder.  I notice that the auto-generated code in `scientists.js` includes with the following:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
});
```

The instructions say that once I've filled out the corresponding `scientists` template with text, I should be able to navigate to `localhost:4200/scientists` and see (among other things) the text I added to the `scientists` template.  However when I do so, the DOM is blank and the console contains an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `@ember/routing/route` imported from `ember-quickstart/routes/foobar`
    at missingModule (loader.js:247)
    at findModule (loader.js:258)
    at Module.findDeps (loader.js:168)
    at findModule (loader.js:262)
    at requireModule (loader.js:24)
    at Class._extractDefaultExport (resolver.js:385)
    at Class.resolveOther (resolver.js:82)
    at Class.superWrapper [as resolveOther] (ember-utils.js:437)
    at Class.resolveRoute (resolver.js:304)
    at Class.resolve (resolver.js:141)
```

From previous work on Ember apps, I know that I could replace the default route contents with the following:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
});
```

And in fact, this does work- I see what I expect to see, with no errors in the console.

My question is, why didn't the instructions produce the results I expected?  I feel like I'm missing something elementary, but the Quick-Start page is pretty short and I don't see where I went wrong.

By the way, I've tried the same steps for generating components as well, which resulted in the same console error.

Answer (score 0):

This module import supported only from ember version 2.16 onwards.

Comment: But the version I have listed in my `package.json` file is version 2.11, and the Quick Start guide I'm following is for version 2.11 as well.  So why would an import statement that's only supported by >= v2.16 be used by the v2.11 `ember generate route` command?  And if this is indeed the cause, why wouldn't the Ember docs mention this?  Seems like a pretty important thing to mention.

Comment: ember-cli version 2.11 will not create blue print with new import syntax. you please confirm are you using the version ember-cli latest

Comment: Running `ember --version` in my project directory produces the following:

ember-cli: 2.11.0
node: 4.5.0
os: darwin x64

Comment: I am using ember-cli version 2.14 in my app, but its not using the latest syntax. In your case ember-cli version globally installed may be latest one

Comment: I don't see a globally-installed version of ember: `npm list -g | grep ember` produces no results.  To be sure, I also ran a plain `npm list -g` and copy/pasted the results to a text file, and did a `cmd-f` for `ember`, and got nothing.

Comment: The above was all performed outside the project directory, to avoid any project-specific settings affecting the search results.

Comment: which ember-cli version is showing  for running `ember --version` outside project directory

Comment: Running `ember --version` from the home directory results in the following:

`[ ~ ] $ ember --version`
`ember-cli: 2.11.0`
`node: 4.5.0`
`os: darwin x64`

Comment: this syntax import Route from '@ember/routing/route'; will not come from ember-cli v 2.11 generated route file. but in your machine environment it's coming. We are missing something obvious reason, but not sure what that is...hope some one will shed some more light on this

Comment: Thanks.  For the sake of completeness, here's a Pastebin link with the full output of `npm list -g` run from the home directory: https://pastebin.com/HbpYa7DC

Comment: Just noticed that the directory listed at the top of the `npm list -g` results was for nvm v4.5.0, but I've frequently been using nvm v7.5.0 throughout my other projects.  I switched to nvm version 7.5.0 (`nvm use 7.5.0`) and re-ran the command, and this time I did see certain Ember-related dependencies including `ember-cli`, but this was still v2.11.  Nothing Ember-related found when searching these results for `2.16`. 
 Here's a 2nd pastebin link with that new output: https://pastebin.com/5R2GRya8